# What's with OpenGL's hash defines?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to write a rendering framework for OpenGL, just had a question regarding OpenGL defines.

I'm wondering if there is a reason why everything in OpenGL is a hash define.
For example, I was stuck for 24 hours on a problem that was simply because I wrote GL_POINT instead of GL_POINTS when trying to render something. Because everything was a hash define, I couldn't even tell what the problem was. I still don't know what GL_POINT actually is

So, for example, I could fix this by going

```
enum Topology
{
   TOPOLOGY_POINT = GL_POINTS,
};
```

right? Is there a reason I might not want to do this?

Edit: Just reiterating my question, is there a reason I wouldn't want to do as I wrote above, where I chuck all topology types into an enum, so I don't have to sift through all the other defines?

Comment: What is your question? Is it "what does `#define` do?" or "why do they use them so frequently?"

Comment: `GL_POINT` is a valid value for the second argument of `glPolygonMode()`. I know because I looked it up when somebody here had the same problem recently... I suspect that enums were not used in the OpenGL headers originally because C did not originally have enums, so not all compilers might have supported them at the time. And once you start in a certain direction, it's hard to change without breaking code.

Comment: Well. The GL uses a single name space for all GLenums, not a separate name space or a separate enum type for each use case. That is just a design descision of the API, which of course might be viewed in historical context.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. So, it's perfectly legitimate for me to do as I did in my example, and there's no other factors for example messing with cross-platform compatibility? Just historical context?

Comment: What you have in mind sounds perfectly fine. As long as you pass the correct values into the OpenGL calls, it doesn't make a difference. You probably meant to type `enum Topology` in your code snippet, not `GLenum Topology`?

Comment: You mean pre-processor definition? Because GL started out designed around C (which lacks namespaces, enums, etc.). There are plenty of other language bindings where GL enumerants really do use a language construct like `enum`.

Comment: Thanks everyone :) was a great help. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't breaking any unspoken rule :)

Comment: One point nobody's mentioned is that the width of an `enum` (number of bytes) is compiler or compiler-setting specific. If they defined a type as an `enum` you'd have to use compiler directives to ensure that every time it was compiled, it was the same number of bytes on every compiler where OpenGL might be used.

Comment: `GLenum` has a required size of 32-bit in the specification (even though only the low-order 16-bits are used), so any language bindings that do use a language construct such as `enum` have to conform to that behavior. This is no different from `GLfloat`, `GLint`, etc. Everything has a specific required size, and platforms already account for that.